# Create new sheets and then import three txt files into their own columns

Tags: excel, vba

So backstory, I am currently copying and pasting three .txt files into their own columns per sheet. However, I have a mass amount of data so copying and pasting three .txt files into their own columns per sheet is time consuming. When I right clicked on the sheet to delete it, I saw the button "View code". In astonishment, I see an opportunity to automate this process to save tons of time. I see a vision of

- specifying pathnames to the .txt files I am copying and pasting
- specifying which column to paste the entire content of the .txt file

**With that said, here is an example of what I would like to accomplish using the VBA system in Excel**

Starting off, here are 9 .txt files that would be imported into the Worksheet:

```
TxtFile1Sheet1.txt
Cow1
Rabbit1
Deer1
Crab1
Goat1
Ducks1

TxtFile2Sheet1.txt
Vegetables1
Eggs1
Meat1
Poultry1
Fish1
Seeds1

TxtFile3Sheet1.txt
Fiction1
Narrative1
Novel1
Thriller1
Mystery1
Poetry1

TxtFile1Sheet2.txt
Cow2
Rabbit2
Deer2
Crab2
Goat2
Ducks2

TxtFile2Sheet2.txt
Vegetables2
Eggs2
Meat2
Poultry2
Fish2
Seeds2

TxtFile3Sheet2.txt
Fiction2
Narrative2
Novel2
Thriller2
Mystery2
Poetry2

TxtFile1Sheet3.txt
Cow3
Rabbit3
Deer3
Crab3
Goat3
Ducks3

TxtFile2Sheet3.txt
Vegetables3
Eggs3
Meat3
Poultry3
Fish3
Seeds3

TxtFile3Sheet3.txt
Fiction3
Narrative3
Novel3
Thriller3
Mystery3
Poetry3
```

Here is the VBA workspace that I want to use to import these txt files to their own columns.
[image]

```
Sub ImportThreeTxtFiles()
'
' ImportThreeTxtFiles Macro
' Import three txt files into three columns per sheet
'

'
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;/Users/MyName/Documents/TxtFile1Sheet1", _
        Destination:=Range("$A$2"))
        .Name = "TxtFile1Sheet1"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .RefreshPeriod = False
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 10000
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Range("B2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;/Users/MyName/Documents/TxtFile2Sheet1", _
        Destination:=Range("$B$2"))
        .Name = "TxtFile2Sheet1"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .RefreshPeriod = False
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 10000
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Range("C2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;/Users/MyName/Documents/TxtFile3Sheet1", _
        Destination:=Range("$C$2"))
        .Name = "TxtFile3Sheet1"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .RefreshPeriod = False
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 10000
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Using this Macro I recorded, I want to import these files into their own sheets. How could I specify the three sets of files I will paste in a form of a loop? As in:

```
FileSet1 = TxtFile1Sheet1.txt, TxtFile2Sheet1.txt, TxtFile3Sheet1.txt


FileSet2 = TxtFile1Sheet2.txt, TxtFile2Sheet2.txt, TxtFile3Sheet2.txt


FileSet3 = TxtFile1Sheet3.txt, TxtFile2Sheet3.txt, TxtFile3Sheet3.txt
```

These columns will be named Animals, Type of Foods, Genres

Here is the desired output:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I am very new to VBA, I have more of a background in Python. This example is meant to be more conceptual. How would I be able to loop or call these files into these three columns? I'd love to see how the community tackles this to learn from it. I am currently watching videos and reading more about it. Thanks!

Comment: No code at all so far. Sorry if that's a deal breaker. :(

Comment: Have you tried using the macro recorder while you do it manually so you can see the basic code for each part?

Comment: I'll look more into the Macro Recorder. Thank you!

Comment: If no answers, I'll update this question with more relevant code. Decided to ask the community outright while I began the research to get more of a direction!

Comment: So, each text file contains only a column. Is that understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, no comma separated values. Line by line import into one column per .txt file

Comment: OK. Please, try making some research on your own and show us a piece of code, even not working as you want. We will help you correcting it, or I will post a different (working) solution...

Comment: Will do!! Planning an all nighter here where I am to figure this out!

Comment: Use Excel macro recorder to generate rough code then refine it. Each file has same number of lines? Why unrelated data side-by-side?

Comment: So I would edit the three path names, then apply the Module/Macro using the shortcut that I assigned to the Macro?

Comment: Okay, I'm going to update this question with more relevant info to express what I am trying to do. Give me a minute!

Comment: By the way, nice to hear from you again June!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, test the next code and send some feedback. Take care of using **the real folder path where the text file exist**:

```
Sub ImportTextFilesInColumns()
  Dim wb As Workbook, sh As Worksheet, strFoldPath As String
  Dim fileName As String, shName As String, colNo As Long, arrHd, arrTxt
  
  Set wb = ActiveWorkbook ' you can set here the workbook you need
  
  arrHd = Split("Animals, Type of Foods, Genres", ", ") 'put the headers string in an array
  strFoldPath = "Your real folder path" 'place here the folder path where the text file exist
  'some optimization: _________________________________________________
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False: Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  '____________________________________________________________________
  'Place the header on the necessary sheets:
  For Each sh In wb.Sheets
        Select Case sh.Name
            Case "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3"
              sh.Range("A1:C1").value = arrHd
        End Select
  Next
  'iterate between all text files in strFolder:
  fileName = dir(strFoldPath & "\*.txt")
  Do While fileName <> ""
        colNo = CLng(Mid(fileName, 8, 1))  'extract column number
        shName = Mid(fileName, 9, 6)       'extract sheet name
        'place the content of the text file in an array:
        arrTxt = Split(CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(strFoldPath & "\" & fileName, 1).ReadAll, vbCrLf)
        wb.Sheets(shName).cells(2, colNo).Resize(UBound(arrTxt) + 1, 1) = Application.Transpose(arrTxt) ' drop the array content

        fileName = dir()                    'continue the iteration between files
  Loop
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True: Application.EnableEvents = True
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

No error handling in case of no sheet with the name extracted from the last 6 digits of the text file (before .txt). You must be atentive when build the txt files name. Such an error handling can be imagined, but not treated in the above code...

Comment: Fane! I'll test this out! Hopefully the updated question didn't throw a curve ball onto this answer!

Comment: @bbsmfb The above code answers the question as it was (previously) formulated. If you still have the text files you copied in your (initial) question, you can test it on them. If not, you should create them. And, even if you edit your question and add some new issues, **you should keep the initial meaning**. Otherwise, somebody else reading my answer will think that I hit my head recently... :)

Comment: I'm sucha noob man! I'm so sorry, I edited the question so it more relates to my situation. I should have made a new one, my apologies. This platform is amazing and I am learning the etiquette. Would you like me to edit the question back it's original state and mark answer as correct?

Comment: @bbsmfb Marking the answer as accepted, is your option according to the way it solved your problem. But it would be good to edit the question and try making it to refer the previous meaning. Then write: **Edited**: and let the actual formulation. I tried above explaining why. Your question and my answer will stay here long time. If somebody else will search for a similar issue, he will understand something from the question against the answer only if they match somehow... If you place a different question and tag me, according to my availability I will try answering it, too.

Comment: I'll be posting in later hours and tag you! If you have the time or not, no big deal! Thanks again!

Comment: Hey @FaneDuru , I created an updated question. If you would be able to check it out when you have the chance and if it's not answered give it a jab. You said I can tag you so reaching out, thanks!

Comment: @bbsmfb When tag me, please also place a link to the question... Now, I will go in your profile and see your questions... It looks we are located in opposite regions of the Earth and when you send the message I was sleeping. I will try posting an answer.